# Trying to learn to combine a form and script to affect my page

Tags: javascript, html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>placeholder</h1>
  <form method="get">
    <label for="word">enter word</label>
    <input id="word" name="word" type="text" maxlength="15">
    <input type="submit">
  </form>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    let actualWord = document.getElementById('word');
    if (actualWord === 'yes') {
     document.querySelector('h1').innerHTML = "oh yeah";
    } else {
      document.querySelector('h1').innerHTML = "error";
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Im very new to the world of coding and im hoping someone could help me with a "simple" test I was trying to perform.

I want this HTML code to replace the "Placeholder" text at the top of the screen with "oh Yeah" if the user types "yes" in the form.

Im hoping someone can tell me what im doing wrong or point me in the right direction.

https://github.com/Uken81/Form-test.git

Comment: you need a button to click that will run the code. Also you are expected to put the code itself in the question, not a link to the code

Comment: I have updated the question with the code properly formatted(I think). Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve that by adding [click event listener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/click) to the `<submit>` button inside the form, and then perform the check on the text `<input>` and use [`.value`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement) attribute to get the `<input>` text value, note that I used `[e.preventDefault()][3]` to prevent the form from redirect, here is a working snippet:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>placeholder</h1>
  <form method="get">
    <label for="word">enter word</label>
    <input id="word" name="word" type="text" maxlength="15">
    <input id="change-placeholder" type="submit">
  </form>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    
    
    document.getElementById('change-placeholder').addEventListener('click', function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      let actualWord = document.getElementById('word').value;
      if (actualWord === 'yes') {
       document.querySelector('h1').innerHTML = "oh yeah";
      } else {
        document.querySelector('h1').innerHTML = "error";
      }
    })
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

**1**.You need to listen to form submit event and trigger a function

**HTML**

```
<form onsubmit="return handleSubmit()">...</form>
```

**Javascript**

```
function handleSubmit(evt) {
 ...
}
```

**2**.You get user's input value like this

```
document.getElementById('word').value
```

**3**.Also you need to prevent form from submitting, By returning `false`

**Full Example**

```js
function handleSubmit(evt) {
  let actualWord = document.getElementById('word').value;
  if (actualWord === 'yes') {
    document.querySelector('h1').innerHTML = "oh yeah";
  }
  return false;
}
```

```html
<h1>placehold</h1>
<form onsubmit="return handleSubmit()">
  <label for="word">enter word</label>
  <input id="word" name="word" type="text" maxlength="15">
</form>
```